# isort sorting things differently when running locally than in CI/other machines

Tags: python, isort

When running isort locally (e.g. `python -m isort .` or `poetry run isort .`, `isort` seems to sort things different than in CI, so my CI job fails when it checks for good formatting using `python -m isort --check-only .`.

### Correct:

```
import azure
import pytest

from my_package_name.example import Example1, Example2
```

### Wrong, running locally

```
import azure

import pytest
from my_package_name.example import Example1, Example2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause

I had an **empty folder called `pytest`**, which tricked `isort` into thinking it was a local module.

Therefore, it moved `import pytest` together with other local imports.

### Solution

After deleting this empty folder, isort sorted the imports correctly again.